# Git pull with untracked local chenges

Tags: git, git-stash

I need to have the updated code from remote repo before pushing my local changes. I have untracked files in my local repository. So when I tried

```
git stash --include-untracked
git pull
git stash apply
```

to stash untracked files before pulling and applying the stashed changes after a `git pull`, The untracked files are not being listed in a `git status`. Where am I wrong?

Comment: `git stash -u` (aka `--include-untracked`) is broken in recent Git versions. I recommend avoiding `git stash` in general as it's kind of flaky.

Comment: can u pls help me to find out how to get remote changes without disturbing local changes?

Comment: Commit the files (add them first as needed). Now they're committed, so they can be replaced with incoming files. Before or after committing, use `git fetch` to bring over the new commits, separately from any merge or rebase that you plan to do. Compare the files *in* those new commits to the untracked files that you will commit or have already committed, and decide how to combine *their* copies of files with those names with *your* copies of files with those names.

Comment: 2 questions : 1. does `git status` say that some files are in a conflicting state ? 2. in the list of staged files, do you see some files that were initially untracked ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to commit (as recommended), I use with success (including in the latest  Git 2.34.x version):

```
git config --global rebase.autostash true
pull.rebase true
```

Then a simple `git pull` is enough (to stash then restore your work in progress)